# What does CAST function do?

Tags: sql, casting

I encountered these statements in the SQL and I don't understand what will be the output using **CAST** function?

These are the statements:

1. `cast(date_var - 19000000 as DATE) + 1  as integer`

will this output the next day of date_var?

2. `cast(substr('date_var',1,6) || '01' as integer) - 10000`

I'm more confused on what will be the output on this?

Comment: 'date_var'... is it a variable.. or string itself?

Comment: Have..... you tried executing them to see what the output is? That'd be a good first step.

Comment: cast is used to convert data types of an existing column. see here: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/cast.php

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific!

Comment: CAST() is used to convert data from one datatype to another.Above statements are converting data type to integer

Answer (score 5):

CAST or CONVERT convert explicit a value form one data type to another.

SQL Syntax 1:

```
CONVERT( datatype, expression [, style] )
```

SQL Syntax 2:

```
CAST( expression AS datatype )
```

Parameters:
        expression
Any expression of any type.
datatype

The new data type. This parameter is not a expression.

style

A integer value for compatible with the MS SQL Server.

Escape Syntax:

```
{fn CONVERT( expression, datatype )}
```

Return Type:
        definite with the parameter datatype.
Examples:

```
SELECT convert( varchar(30), price )
SELECT convert( nvarchar(30), now(), 102)
SELECT {fn convert( {fn now()}, nvarchar(30))}
SELECT cast( price as varchar(30)
```

[Source](http://www.smallsql.de/doc/sql-functions/system/convert.html)

Answer (score 4):

The `CAST()` function converts a value of any type into a value that has a specified type.

The target type can be any one of the following types: 
**BINARY, CHAR, DATE, DATETIME, TIME,DECIMAL, SIGNED, UNSIGNED**.

syntax:- `CAST(expr AS type)`

ex:-1

```
mysql> SELECT NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2017-02-06 10:49:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CAST(NOW() as DATE);
 +---------------------+
| CAST(NOW() as DATE) |
+---------------------+
| 2017-02-06          |
+---------------------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

ex:-2

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(-1 as signed);
       +--------------------+
       | CAST(-1 as signed) |
       +--------------------+
       |                 -1 |
       +--------------------+
      1 row in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql> SELECT CAST(-1 as unsigned);
       +----------------------+
       | CAST(-1 as unsigned) |
       +----------------------+
       | 18446744073709551615 |
       +----------------------+
     1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```